# Decoding delay in vlc player client when transmitting RTP + h264 packet

Tags: h.264, vlc, rtsp, rtp

I developed an rtsp server to communicate with the vlc client.
The role of the server is as follows:
Connect the vlc client to the rtsp session.
It is to get the h264 payload from a specific pcap file and send it to the client with an rtp header.

It is well implemented, but there is one problem.

This means that the rtsp session must be terminated (TEARDOWN), but the decoding is initiated.

I hope to see the video in real time.

I want you to suggest a wise solution.

Attempted to raise the cache of the vlc client (30000ms)
The problem is still not solved, but I feel that the quality of the decoded image has improved.

I hope for a solution for real-time image decoding.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
Turns out to be a timestamp issue in rtp packets.
When I sent the packet, I sent it as a realtime, but the interval was too short and the decoding was delayed.
When sending a packet, the problem is solved by forcing a suitable interval.